# create file unix using Loop

Tags: unix, createfile

I have a list of 87 text files populated daily in UNIX.

Eg: FP*.txt --- file names start with FP & are txt files
Daily new content gets appended to the end. I want to take a back up of all the text files using shell script and create blank files of the same name. I tried the following.

```
echo "" > FP*.txt
```

and `> FP*.txt`

Both gave the same error.

```
FP*.txt: ambiguous redirect
```

however when used on single file both work fine. So how to resolve it. And also creating a list of hard-coded names is not an option, as 87 are too many and they may increase in future.

Also some file names contain ( & , in their names. When tried the following codes,

```
echo "" > FP---Sample.txt
```

This worked fine. But when tried the following gave error.

```
echo "" > FP(1)---Sample.txt
```

This gave an error.

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

So how to accomplish it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the filename in quotes:

```
echo "" > "FP(1)---Sample.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a

> FP*.txt: ambiguous redirect

because you can just redirect to one file, while `FP*.txt` expands to more than one. That's why it works when the expansion just returns one name.

To do what you need, you'd better loop through the results of `FP*.txt`. For example, you can use:

```
bk_date=$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")       # 20140210_150526 format of date
for file in FP*.txt
do
   cp -p "$file" "${file}.${bk_date}"  # make a backup of the file
   > "$file"                   # blank it. This is same as echo "" > "$file"
done
```

Regarding the error:

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

[Martin Dinov correctly explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21679271/1983854) that you need to quote the name to make it be part of the file name.

Comment: thanxs.. that sorted it out